# Android onConfigurationChanged not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent, orientation

First time I've ever tried this so do not know about it but need it fixed ASAP. Im trying to make it do a new intent when i rotate the device to landscape.

Here's my code:

```
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),                      
                VideoLandscape.class);
        i.putExtra("url", LINK);
        i.putExtra("small", videoPath);
        startActivity(i);

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }


//Manifest
 <activity
        android:name="com.****.media.tv.Video"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/title_TV">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.****.media.tv.VideoLandscape"
        android:label="@string/title_TV">
    </activity>
```

Many Thanks 
Charlton Santana

Comment: Put the same `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` for `com.****.media.tv.VideoLandscape` and also in the code in the `else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){` put the new intent start for the First activity: `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),                      
                VideoPortrait.class);
        i.putExtra("url", LINK);
        i.putExtra("small", videoPath);
        startActivity(i);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

in activity tag of meanifeast

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `|screenSize` attribute in `android:configChanges` attribute like given below

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Since there is a little change after API level 13 which is mentioned in the doc for handeling `onConfigurationChanged()`

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size" also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation" value. That is, you must decalare android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).

[From here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)